# Difficulty with getElementById

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript and having a play around with some functions, but having difficulty with the getElementBy tag.

Any tag that I use i.e. with Id, ClassName, TagName does not seem to work, however if I use the TagName with an array following it, it seems to work.

For example:

`document.getElementsByTagName("p").style.background = "yellow";` - does not work.

`document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].style.background = "yellow";` - works

Can any help me solve this or explain why this might be doing this?

Thanks

Comment: `document.getElementById('id');` should work without issue unless you are dealing with old Internet Explorer versions, or running in quirks mode. are you sure you have a single element with the exact ID you are searching for?

Comment: Please remove the 'separate note' part of the question and post is as a new question.

Comment: I've added an example into my answer on how to update all paragraphs at once.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `getElementById()` is designed to find a single element with a unique id in the DOM.

`getElementsByTagName` or fetching them via class can return multiple elements, as elements or classes are not required to be unique in the dom.

Hence the square brackets. `document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]` gets the first `<p></p>` tag in the DOM. `document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1]` would get the second found paragraph element.

EDIT: Example to change background color of all `<p></p>` elements within the DOM via `getElementsByTagName`.

```
var pElementArray = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(var i = 0; i < pElementArray.length; i++) {
    pElementArray[i].style.background = "yellow";
}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the getElementByTagName("p") I believe should get all p within the document, but it doesn't seem to get any. I.e. there is no response if I change it to: document.getElementsByTagName("p").style.background = "yellow";.

Comment: `getElementByTagName("p")` isn't a function. `getElementsByTagName("p")` is however (notice the extra 's'). `getElementsByTagName("p")` returns multiple paragraph elements, you need to select one before you can do anything.

Comment: Ok, sorry I am using it with a extra 's'. When you say I need to select one can I not select all the paragraph tags? I am also still confused as to why the getElementsByClassName does not work.

Comment: @PaulLipman You could easily store the result from `getElementsByTagName("p")` into a variable, loop over that variable, and set the background that way. I will edit my answer

Comment: Thanks Robin, yes I can see how that works, however I am not too worried about the function of changing the background yellow, but to understand the getElementBy(Id,TagName, ClassName) function so I know how to use it in future. Is it not a function that can be used individually?

Comment: `getElementBy(Id,TagName, ClassName)` is not a function. `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByClassName` are.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByTagName` results in an array of DOM elements. This is why you're using square brackets (`[0]`) to select the first one or `[1]` to select the second.

There is no `document.getElementByTagName('p')` function.

To change all paragraphs, you must first loop through them:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
  var paragraph = paragraphs[i];
  paragraph.style.background = "yellow";
}
```

---

Remember, these are all functions. There not grouped by the name "getElementBy", that's just a name they share.

`getElementsByClassName` requires a classname not a tag and returns many items.

`getElementById` requires an ID not a tag and only returns one item.

---

> From [Huan Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4899560/huan-zhang)
>
> Most of the answer above have already explained why using [0] works. I just > wanted to elaborate that since
>
> ```
> document.getElementsByTagName('p')
> ```
>
> returns an array,
>
> ```
> document.getElementsByTagName("p").style.background = "yellow";
> ```
>
> is basically trying to set the background image of yellow onto an array, which for obvious reasons does not work.
>
> You can create a simple for loop to set a yellow background on each element within that array as a work around.

---

> From [Olivier Krull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4952537/olivier-krull)
>
> The for loop that @HuanZhang mentioned could look like this:
>
> ```
> var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')
> for(i =0; i<p.length ;i++){
>   p[i].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm still having difficulty, if I change it to getElementsByClassName("yellow").style.background = "yellow"; (and add the "yellow" class name to a paragraph tag) I thought it would change that paragraph so the background is yellow, but nothing happens?

Comment: To change all paragraphs you must loop through them.

Answer (score 2):

The for loop which @Huan Zhang mentioned could look like this:

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for(i =0; i<p.length ;i++){
  p[i].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
};
```

This should work for you